# WebStorm not showing terminal path on the first instance

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I love WebStorm and have been using it for almost 2+ years now. Recently I am facing the problem when you open up a project and click terminal it is not showing terminal current path on the first instance. Just getting blank screen.

Every time I need to hit enter at least once or twice to get the current path.

This problem is occurring for my **colleagues** as well.

[image]

We all use WebStorm effectively. Would be great if any one help to solve this problem please.

This is my WebStorm version

[image]

Comment: Which terminal are you using? (You should be able to see this in File->Settings->Tools->Terminal)

Comment: C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe. The normal cmd prompt

Comment: What happens if you select a different terimnal (like Powershell)? Does it start rendering correct again?

Comment: just switched to powershell. Still facing the same problem

Comment: Hmm.. I had a similar issue once, but that went away when I switched to Powershell... I don't think I can be of more help then. I'll leave you with an upvote and hope someone else can help you :)

Comment: Tried the invalidates caches and restart. no luck.   But thanks Daniel for your quick assistance.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a known issue, please see on JetBrains' issue tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-192373 .

Comment: Thank you for this. I will wait for the jet brain teams to provide solution